# MVC Core : Upload file through Ajax request and return JSON object without redirect

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, file-upload, .net-core

I have a requirement where I want to upload an excel file to the controller, read the file, process its data and send it back to the same view as the JSON object.

I want to achieve this using AJAX call as I want to capture its success callback and manipulate DOM as per received response. I have tried a few things but I am not able to hit the controller. Any help on this is appreciated.

Below shown is my **JS**, **HTML** and **C#** code :

```js
function SubmitInfo() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', $('#fileInput')[0].files[0]); // myFile is the input type="file" control

    var _url = '@Url.Action("Upload", "CrossValidation")';

    $.ajax({
        url: _url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        processData: true,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
        contentType: false,  // tell jQuery not to set contentType
        success: function (result) {
            //manipulate DOM and bind response with Kendo grid
            alert("result");
        },
        error: function (jqXHR) {
        },
        complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
    <input id="fileInput" type="file">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload file" onclick="SubmitInfo()"/>
</div>
```

```cs
public JsonResult Upload(IFormFile formData)
{
    //Do something here....
    return Json("");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two obvious problems in the code you've posted:

1. `processData: true`. By setting this to `true` (the default), you're asking jQuery to attempt to turn the `data` you're providing into a query string, which is not what you want. Instead, you want to set this to `false`, which will ask jQuery to leave the data alone and pass it on to the underlying `XMLHttpRequest` as is, where the data will be formatted correctly as multipart/form-data.
2. The `name` argument passed to `formData.append` must match the name of your `IFormFile` parameter in the ASP.NET Core MVC Controller. You're using `file` in the the former and `formData` in the latter, so you'll need to change one of them so that they're the same.